# Destructor getting called on protobuf object

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I've implemented two simple protobuf messages

```
package TestNamespace;
message Object1 {
  int32 age = 1;
  int32 speed = 2;
}

message Object2 {
  Object1 obj = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
}
```

I then have two wrapper classes of the protobuf objects.
Inside the Object2Wrapper, after I call ToProtobuf when it returns the destructor is called on obj1 for some reason I cannot understand.

```
class Object1Wrapper
    {
    public:
        int32_t Age{};
        int32_t Speed{};

        void ToProtobuf(TestNamespace::Object1 obj1)
        {
            obj1.set_age(Age);
            obj1.set_speed(Speed);
            //After this line the ~destructor is called on obj1
        }
};

class Object2Wrapper{

    public:
        Object1Wrapper obj1{};
        int32_t page_number{};

        void ToProtobuf(TestNamespace::Object2 obj2Param)
        {
            TestNamespace::Object1 * obj1Proto = obj2Param.mutable_obj();
            obj1::ToProtobuf(*obj1Proto);
            // Do stuff.... but obj1Proto is empty
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you pass the object `obj1` by value. A copy of the parameter is created and this copy is destroyed when the function returns.\

I guess what you really wanted to do is to pass the object by reference. I.e.

```
void ToProtobuf(TestNamespace::Object1& obj1)
    {
        obj1.set_age(Age);
        obj1.set_speed(Speed);
        //After this line the ~destructor is called on obj1
    }
```

Only when you pass-by-reference, you can alter the object inside the function. As you have it now, any changes to `obj1` inside the function have zero effect on the parameter that is passed to the function.

Comment: Oh god you're right! Still getting the hang on c++ after moving from java ^^